# Remember Password based on two fields

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

Normally a login page contains two textboxes one for username another for password

In an Asp.net 3.0 SaaS product we are developing has three text boxes 1) Customer Name, 2) User Name and 3) password.

There is checkbox on login page i.e. Remember Password

Write now it is functioning based on User Name (as normal login page does)

I want to save password for a combination of Customer Name and User Name and not only based on User Name as user names can be same for two customers.

Yes I left it on browser and it autofill the password just after filling User Name and moving out of textbox and it is working fine.

I want password textbox to be filled based on username and customername.

How to achieve this , any approach is fine but it should work as required.

Comment: How are you "remembering" the password? server side? client-side cookie? other?

Comment: Let the *browser* remember *passwords* (e.g. where it asks "Do you want to remember password for xyz?"). It's okay (or more accepted) to remember *sessions* (e.g. "Keep me logged in" checkbox on login page). The problem with remembering *passwords* is that then they need to be exposed in plaintext in a few locations (although, HTTPS, as always, can help).

Comment: You can write your own, or override the asp.net membership (login) methods...

Comment: Although never tried and not very intuitive, you could use different [application names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.applicationname.aspx) to achieve your functionality for different customers without conflicting with duplicate user-names or emails.

Comment: @pst browser only remember password by username field not by the combination

Comment: By the way, here's the same question. http://forums.silverlight.net/t/93216.aspx/1 Maybe it's the best to roll out a custom membership provider.

Comment: just use different links/pages for customers (fork earlier, each have their own login or something) and that page will then be able to auto-fill (on the login page just username / pass) - similar to what @TimSchmelter suggested previously (i.e. autofill won't work otherwise, if more than user/pass)

Answer (score 0):

You can store your username/customer namme and also password in cookie which is a browser functionality. And then retrieve this all three Fileds  while page load from cookie ..